# fast way to make all elements in a 2d array becomes certain non-zero value in C++

Tags: c++

Say I want to assign 5 to all the elements in a 2d array. First I tried memset

```
int a[3][4];
memset(a, 5, sizeof a);
```

and

```
int a[3][4];
memset(a, 5, sizeof(a[0][0])*3*4);
```

But the same result is `all the elements becomes 84215045`.

Then I tried with `fill_n`, it showed buildup failed. it seems `fill_n` cannot do with 2d array.

So is there any fast way to make all the elements in a 2d array to a certain value?   in C++?

```
********************************************************************************
UPDATE
```

Thanks @paddy for the answer. Actually `fill_n` does work. The way I used it is like this, which fails to build up with my compiler.

```
fill_n(a,3*4,5);
```

@paddy's answer is correct, we can use it in this way for a 2d array.

```
fill_n(a[0],3*4,5);
```

Then I tried a little more, I found we can actually use this to deal with a 3d array, but it should be like this. Say for `a[3][4][5]`.

```
fill_n(a[0][0],3*4*5,5);
```

Comment: std::valarray and std::vector both have constructors to initialize all elements to a known value, however they are not exactly 2d arrays. Since this is a C++ question, a good solution is to make a wrapper class over std::vector or std::valarray and provide 2d accessors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `memset` is only useful for setting every *byte* to a value.  But that won't work when you want to set groups of bytes.  Because of the memory layout of a 2D array, it's actually okay to use `std::fill_n` or `std::fill` from the first value:

```
std::fill_n( a[0], 3 * 4, 5 );
std::fill( a[0], a[3], 5 );  // Note a[3] is one past the end of array.
```

Depending on your compiler, something like this might even be *vectorized* for even faster execution.  But even without that, you ought not to worry about speed -- `std::fill` is plenty fast.

Answer (score -3):

sizeof(a) will give you the size of a pointer in byte, which will depend on the system it is running. On a 32 bit system or OS, it's 4 (32 bits = 4 bytes), on a 64 bits system/OS, it's 8.

to get the size of an int array of 3x4 elements, you should use sizeof(int)*(3*4).

So, you should use memset(a, 5, sizeof(int)*(3*4));

Comment: **−1** "sizeof(a) will give you the size of a pointer in byte" is nonsense.

Comment: To get the size of an int array of 3x4 elements, you should rather use `sizeof(int[3][4])`. Or just `sizeof(a)`, which gives the size of the array. There's no pointer anywhere.